# Remove master key requirement from sql server database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

We restored a database from one environment to another.  The original environment was using TDE, and this was disabled for the new environment:

```
SELECT *, db_name(database_id), encryption_state  
FROM sys.dm_database_encryption_keys

database_id encryption_state
----------- ---------------- 
7           1                
10          1
```

However, the databases still need to be opened under the master key before they come online.  The following error occurs:

Msg 15581, Level 16, State 3, Line 3
Please create a master key in the database or open the master key in the session before performing this operation.

The databases can be brought back online with:

```
OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'xxx';
alter database ally_orgunit set online
```

How do I completely remove the need for the master key on these databases?

Comment: So you want to know how to bypass a crucial security mechanism for a database you own. Except we don't know that you own this database.

Comment: When you say that the databases are offline, is it the TDE that's preventing it from coming online? If so, backup and restore the certificate that's used to protect the database encryption key on the source server to the destination server. The certificate will live in master at both the source and the destination.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - no I have the keys and I'm able to bring the database up after I open the key.  My question is, now that I have disabled encryption on the DB (encryption_state=1), how do I also remove the dependency on the master key.

Comment: @BenThul - key is already installed on the destination server - that is what I open (I have the actual 'xxx' password).  But I'm confused on why I need to do with when encryption is no longer enabled on either of those databases.

Comment: You mentioned a key (which comes over with the database), I mentioned a certificate (which lives in master). Are you sure you've got the right of it?

Comment: @BenThul - Oops sorry.  Yes, the certificate is installed and visible in sys.certificates.  Encryption was enabled and working on these two databases.  However, we were bit by a microsoft bug that made the database inaccessible (after a backup I believe) so we opted to disable the encryption.  So I expected the need for opening the master key in order to bring the databases online to go away.

Comment: Sorry, don't how reorient object applies.

Comment: Ha! In reply to wrong post. :)